# Missing arument controller php CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have problem in controller

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for pembayaran::konfirmasi_form()
>
> Filename: controllers/pembayaran.php
>
> Line Number: 67
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\AppServ\www\PROJEK\application\controllers\pembayaran.php
>   Line: 67 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\AppServ\www\PROJEK\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

**this controller**

```
function konfirmasi_form($id_pesanan)
{
    $pesanan = $this->pesanan_model->ambil_data_id($id_pesanan);
    $data = array(
        'aksi'                  => site_url('pembayaran/konfirmasi_pembayaran'),
        'id_pesanan'                => set_value('id_pesanan',$pesanan->id_pesanan),
        'id_member'                 => set_value('id_member',$pesanan->id_member),
        'id_barang'                 => set_value('id_barang',$pesanan->id_barang),
        'tanggal_pesanan'               => set_value('tanggal_pesanan',$pesanan->tanggal_pesanan),
        'status_pesanan'                => set_value('status_pesanan',$pesanan->status_pesanan),
        'jumlah_barang_pesanan'             => set_value('jumlah_barang_pesanan',$pesanan->jumlah_barang_pesanan),
        'total_bayar_pesanan'           => set_value('total_bayar_pesanan',$pesanan->total_bayar_pesanan),
        'barang_pesanan'                => set_value('barang_pesanan',$pesanan->barang_pesanan),
        'jasa_pesanan'              => set_value('jasa_pesanan',$pesanan->jasa_pesanan),
        'button'                    => 'BAYAR'
        );


    $this->load->view('Utama/pembayaran_form',$data);       
}
```

Comment: pembayaran.php .. line 67 .. post that ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that a call to method was made but no argument was provided, but the argument is required. In short it means that somewhere a call like this was made

```
 $this->pembayaran->konfirmasi_form();
```

but the code should look more like this

```
$this->pembayaran->konfirmasi_form($some_value_here);
```

Comment: this problem ?redirect(site_url('pembayaran/konfirmasi_form'.$value->id_pesanan));

Comment: Try adding a forward slash '/' after `/konfirmasi_form`        `redirect(site_url('pembayaran/konfirmasi_form/'.$value->id_p‌​esanan));`